# Ansible says parameter does not exist

Tags: ansible

I've got a very strange issue with Ansible. My playbook has a task which needs

line: "hostssl all             postgres        {{ hostvars[item['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']

in a lineinfile operation. When this gets invoked without --limit=one_host, it runs perfectly, yet if I specify --limit=one_host, the playbook throws an error when it hits this task saying  {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4']

Also, I can run: ansible -i environments/sandbox all -m setup --limit=one_host | grep -A 10 ansible_default_ipv4

and see the data structure the playbook needs. So, why does Ansible say it doesn't exist?

Jay

Answer (score 2):

`ansible_default_ipv4` is computed in the fact gathering phase, but only on the play target hosts. By limiting the playbook to 'one_host', this variable is not computed for other hosts, and, as suggested by the use of `hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']`, you are trying to access it for other hosts.

This is a drawback of the `--limit` option.

A solution is to explicitly use the `setup` module (the one automatically used in the fact gathering), in a loop on all the hosts you need to get this variable from, combined with a `delegate_to` and `delegate_facts` (also you can use the `filter` option of the module to only compute the 'default_ipv4' instead of all the facts).